# meaning of the word "scrabblization"?

Tags: meaning

I have come across it in a  [TED video](https://youtu.be/NgDGlcxYrhQ) . It is at 1 minute and 6 second. Here is the context:

> Agloe is a **scrabblization** of the initials of the two guys who made this map.

I have looked up the word on the internet and no definition came up. I suspect the noun *scrabblization*  derives from the verb *scrabble*, but still I cannot make head nor tail of the sentence.

Comment: There is a board game called *Scrabble* in which players draw tiles with letters on them, which they keep hidden from the other players. The goal is to to form words from these tiles, and the letters do not all have the same face value. Some are worth more than others. https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/mattels-family-board-game-scrabble-picture-id458646231?k=6&m=458646231&s=612x612&w=0&h=3gVXw2y8cQPqLeTQTeoCwGAcqYnlGrq-0POCx7N68yY=  (German version of the board)  The letters are arranged on a little wooden rack while they player is looking for places on the board to use the tiles in a word.

Comment: The word **scrabbleization** is a coinage that alludes to the board game; it's not in common use. The letters a player draws and arranges on the rack will often look like gibberish, random letters arranged side-by-side, like AGLOE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, **scrabbilization** is being used as a Scrabble-inspired synonym for [anagram](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anagram):

> 1 : a word or phrase made by transposing the letters of another word or
>   phrase · The word "secure" is an anagram of "rescue."
>
> 2 **anagrams** *plural in form but singular in construction* : a game in
>   which words are formed by rearranging the letters of other words or by
>   arranging letters taken (as from a stock of cards or blocks) at random

Scrabble is just a popular game that makes use of **anagrams**.

If you want to understand the relationship between *Agloe* and the initials of the mapmakers, refer to the definition of **anagram**.

Note: Unlike **scrabbilization**, you *will* find **anagrammatization** in most dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

As the commenter wrote: "The word scrabbleization is a coinage that alludes to the board game; it's not in common use."    So, that is the answer...

Another related game is the Jumble Puzzle, where letters are mixed up. They might just as well have used an invented word or phrase based on "Jumble".